# Log data along with transactions on the blockchain

Tags: ether, truffle

I have a smart contract and on my web interface I'd like to display the 5 latest transactions. Currently these include any ether being sent to my contract which are retrieved using `web3.eth.getTransaction()` and transaction hash.

However, I have a variable `leaf` which any address is allowed to buy, this is logged using an event function. Can the number of leaf purchased be logged and retrieved using the transaction hash?

EDIT: So, I've managed to retrieve all the events using the `allEvents()` functions. Unfortunately, it returns two different structured objects:

The first one, returns this, which contains the `args` variable - as expected:

- Event:   `event depositedFunds(uint amount, uint newBalance);`
- Returned object: `{logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x82b69effb105ef1998fefdbf47d471c54c33a5b3b6b6462da33ecb790b2ce410", blockHash: "0xd16a7efac06f35725ae75bc3bca5a862a2847a94c2f2084c6a6f4d22c71958ec", blockNumber: 3, …}`

The second, which is logged when the desired event is called returns this, which does not contain the `args` variable:

- Event: `event leafWasPicked(uint leavesLeft, uint numberTaken);`
- Returned object: `{logIndex: "0x0", transactionIndex: "0x0", transactionHash: "0xbfd6a21c6d782e18f7636be9895849de8333678f5d7d28a0a406575988e7d653", blockHash: "0x765264a7c21d9c088adfc70a15a69a7b3f3c0408eb3758390bda2596d47aa48f", blockNumber: "0x5", …}`

Why are both of these different?

Comment: I would suggest using Events and then use a filter to get the latest 5 transactions and also getting the `leaf` purchused using events. More infor how to get the log (event) here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution but here's the error when fetching events using the `allEvents` functions: When it return this: `{logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0xc88bc5a0c318a9cc74d8f", blockHash: "0xea475411b5b18be2b7e5a0d7ae231dc1329", blockNumber: 31, …}` the event is correctly logged inside it. But when the event function that I actually need is called it returns this which does not contain log information: `{logIndex: "0x0", transactionIndex: "0x0", transactionHash: "0x7035283a8eafacb754399110be2", blockHash: "0xf9162db97c83e68c4a777", blockNumber: "0x21", …}`

Comment: For clarity, hashes were shortened to match max word count.

Comment: check how you are calling the events or creating the event you need. It should work